# How to start the object in the Main Method (Console)?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have created a new class, `ArraysHandling`. In this class I have a method with arrays. I want call this method in the main method. But something goes wrong! How do I correct call up this method in the main method?

I have created a new object in the main method with the name `learningArrays`. After that, I have called`Console.WriteLine(numb)`.

```
  namespace HelloWorld 

   { public class ArraysHandling  //Creating a new Class
      { 
         public void arrays()
         {
           int[] numb = new int[3] { 8, 9, 10 };
         }                    
       }
     }


 //Main Method
 static void Main(string[] args)

    {
       ArraysHandling learningArrays = new ArraysHandling();           
       Console.WriteLine(numb);
    }
```

I expect in the console to pop up the number: 8, 9, 10.

This creates 2 Errors:

1. Are you missing a using or an assembly reference?
2. The name (numb) does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

The variable numb is a local variable of the method arrays in the class ArraysHandling. Main has no knowledge of it. Make it a field of ArraysHandling and then use it in Main:

```
namespace HelloWorld 
{ 
    public class ArraysHandling  //Creating a new Class
    { 
       public int[] numb;

       public void arrays()
       {
         this.numb = new int[3] { 8, 9, 10 };
       }                    
     }
   }    

   //Main Method
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       ArraysHandling learningArrays = new ArraysHandling();   
       learningArrays.arrays();        
       Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", learningArrays.numb));
   }
}
```

Comment: That would print ```System.Int32[]``` to the console, which is not the wanted output.

Comment: You are right! Just concentrated on solving the exception not on the output. I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @Damir Welcome to StackOverflow. The best way of saying thank you here is [to mark the answer that helped you as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)